# Unexpected NullPointerException throws in Hibernate test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, frameworks, nullpointerexception

Within the project was created ORM model and were written tests. Everything was OK, until model has not changed. One-to-one relation was added and after that tests have become to return NullPointerException.

There are two classes with one-to-one relation in cutted code.

**Class Passport:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PASSPORTS")
public class Passport extends BaseObject implements Serializable {

   private User user;
   private String firstName, lastName;

   // other fields...

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn (name="USER_ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", length = 60)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", length = 80)
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    // other getters-setters...
}
```

And **class User:**

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User extends BaseObject implements Serializable, UserDetails {

private Passport passport;
private Long id;

// other fields...

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "USERS_SEQ", sequenceName = "USERS_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USERS_SEQ")
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}



@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Passport getPassport() {
    return this.passport;
}

public void setPassport(Passport passport) {
    this.passport = passport;
}


public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
} 

@Transient
public String getFirstName() {
    return getPassport().getFirstName();
}

@Transient
public String getLastName() {
    return getPassport().getLastName();
}

@Transient
public String getFullName() {
    return getPassport().getFirstName() + " " + getPassport().getLastName();
}

@Transient
public String getMiddleName() {
    return getPassport().getMiddleName();
}

@Transient
public void setFirstName(String name) {
    getPassport().setFirstName(name);
}

@Transient
public void setLastName(String name) {
    getPassport().setLastName(name);
}

@Transient
public void setMiddleName(String name) {
    getPassport().setMiddleName(name);
}

// other getters-setters...

}
```

And now tests:

```
public class UserDaoTest extends BaseDaoTestCase {
@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;
@Autowired
private RoleDao roleDao;


@Test(expected = HibernateSystemException.class)
public void testUpdateUser() throws Exception {
    User user = userDao.get(-1L);

    Address address = user.getAddress();

    userDao.saveUser(user);
    flush();

    user = userDao.get(-1L);
    assertEquals(address, user.getAddress());

    User user2 = new User();
    user2.setAddress(user.getAddress());
    user2.setConfirmPassword(user.getConfirmPassword());
    user2.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    user2.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
    user2.setLastName(user.getLastName());
    user2.setPassword(user.getPassword());
    user2.setPasswordHint(user.getPasswordHint());
    user2.setRoles(user.getRoles());
    user2.setUsername(user.getUsername());

    userDao.saveUser(user2);
}

@Test(expected = DataAccessException.class)
public void testAddAndRemoveUser() throws Exception {
    User user = new User("testuser");
    user.setPassword("testpass");
    user.setFirstName("Test");
    user.setLastName("Last");
    Address address = new Address();
    user.setAddress(address);
    user.setEmail("testuser@appfuse.org");

    Role role = roleDao.getRoleByName(Constants.USER_ROLE);
    assertNotNull(role.getId());
    user.addRole(role);

    user = userDao.saveUser(user);
    flush();

    assertNotNull(user.getId());
    user = userDao.get(user.getId());
    assertEquals("testpass", user.getPassword());

    userDao.remove(user);
    flush();

    // should throw DataAccessException
    userDao.get(user.getId());
}
}
```

**Result of test:**

```
  testUpdateUser(uz.eopc.dao.UserDaoTest): Unexpected exception, expected<org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException> but was<java.lang.NullPointerException>
  testAddAndRemoveUser(uz.eopc.dao.UserDaoTest): Unexpected exception, expected<org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException> but was<java.lang.NullPointerException>
  testAddAndRemoveUser(uz.eopc.service.impl.UserManagerImplTest): Unexpected exception, expected<org.apache.commons.beanutils.NestedNullException> but was<java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException>
  testAddExistingUser(uz.eopc.service.UserExistsExceptionTest): Unexpected exception, expected<uz.eopc.service.UserExistsException> but was<org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException>
  testAddAndRemoveUser(uz.eopc.service.UserManagerTest): Unexpected exception, expected<org.apache.commons.beanutils.NestedNullException> but was<java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException>
```

It seems one-to-one relation doesn't work and I don't know why.

Yes, project use Spring Framework, but if I run this code without Spring, code works fine without any exception.

Sorry for too long question, I hope anybody can help me.

P. S.

Spring Framework version is **4.0.0.RELEASE**

Hibernate version is **4.2.7.FINAL**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found reason of exception. I use AppFuse Application Framework and it imposes special requirements to model and test classes. Must be created special DAO class to gain access to hibernate session and then you can get data from DB. Exception occurred because my Passport class had no access to session directly.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be changing:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn (name="USER_ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
```

To

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn (name="USER_ID")
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
```

The User join table should be insertable and updatable. Otherwise you'll not be able to update or insert in the join column. This is probably the issue.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @lauksas Removing updatable-insertable part throws additional exceptions with message: Repeated column in mapping for entity: `Passport column: USER_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`, therefore I added this part. But again, I can delete this part when I don't use Spring and just write code directly into main().